# how to insert mathematical equation in pdf flutter?

Tags: flutter, pdf, latex, mathtype

How to generate a pdf that contain complex mathematical equations in flutter

complex mathematical equations

[image: 1]

I have used the [pdf](https://pub.dev/packages/pdf) package to generate pdf, i can easily insert text , image but when it comes to mathType equation i can't. I dont want to use image for inserting equation. I have been stuck with this for days.

please help and thank you all in advance.

Comment: currently pdf did not support katex but the simple way is to convert build widget into  image and use that image to save in the pdf